# Using Eval as a variable?

Tags: php, eval

> I know that a lot would be against using eval, but I do know the
>   dangers. Everything I use eval for will be for my own use and no user
>   input will be used.

I'm trying to grab some content by using $Content = "Content here"; But I also need to use `eval($content);` as the value of content will be containing php code that i'll need to execute. I also want to be able to use eval as a value. So for example using `$Example = eval($content);`

As I said, I know it can be dangerous, But its a risk im going to take to handle it. I'd just like my question to be answered. Thank you in advance

Comment: This is all fine. The question is: _what is your question?_...

Comment: How would I be able to use Eval as a variable. Such as $Test = eval('lala'); and then using echo $test; somewhere on a page

Comment: I suggest you simply take a look at the documentation, which always is the first place you should look. It clearly answers your question: http://php.net/manual/de/function.eval.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of use of `eval` that returns a value:

```
php > $a = 'return 3+3;';
php > $b = eval($a);
php > echo $b;
6
```

As written in a comment, read always the documentation. In this case, the page about [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I tried this, and this worked. Although i'm trying to use $Content as the value of $a such as `$a = $Content;
$b = eval($a);
echo $b;` although when I do this, this makes echo $b; useless as it seems that when I remove it, it comes up anyways which is not what I want. How could I fix this? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. What does it means “this makes echo $b; useless as it seems that when I remove it, it comes up anyways which is not what I want”?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explaining. So I'm using what you supplied. But when I replace $a = $Content, it shows the content whether or not I have echo $b. So if I remove echo $b it still shows.

Comment: First,`$a = $Content` only assigns the value of the variable `$Content` to the variable `$a`, why you need this? You could use directly `$Content`, for instance with `eval($Content)`. Then, if `$Content` contains statements of any kind, doing `eval` on it *will* execute those statements; if, at the end of the statements, there is a `return expression;`, than *only* the value of that expression will be assigned to the variable `$b`. If you do `echo $b;` than this value will be inserted in the current page, and *only* this value.

Comment: How could I use $b = eval($Content); without it executing it and showing up without me using echo $b;

Comment: If you do `eval($Content$)` **it will be executed**. If you want to show only what is the value of the variable `$Content` then do `echo $Content;`.

Comment: I need it to be eval